Find one quartic root of a matrix

I have found the previous spectral decomposition of the matrix $$A=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 & 0 \\
0&1&1\\
1&0&1
 \end{pmatrix}.$$
You can see I verified such decomposition indeed yields the matrix $A$.
I was asked to find one $4$th root $A$.
I tried to find a 4th root of $A$ by taking the $4$th root of the diagonal matrix whose diagonal entries are the eigenvalues of $A$. In other words, taking the $1/4$ power of each diagonal entry, but the software I was working with could not answer me. How should I proceed in this case?
PS: I was working with a symbol because I tried to use Wolfram Alpha at first, but I got an error message, so I moved on to the symbol to verify that such spectral decomposition yields $A$. After that, I kept working with symbols in my attempt to find the quartic root, but alas, it said that such matrix powers are not supported

Frankly, why on earth do you need to do a spectral decomposition, not to say using a computer? The matrix $A$ is $I+P$, where $P$ is a permutation matrix corresponding to a shift. The minimal polynomial of $P$ is clearly $x^3-1$. Hence the eigenvalues of $A$ are $1+1,,1+a$ and $1+\overline{a}$ where $a=\exp(2\pi i/3)$. If you put $w=\exp(\pi i/12)$, then the eigenvalues of $A$ are $2,w^4$ and $\overline{w}^4$. So, if $p$ is the Lagrange interpolation polyomial that maps $2,w^4,\overline{w}^4$ to $2^{1/4},w,\overline{w}$ respectively, then $p(A)$ is a quartic root of $A$.

put another way, your fourth root   is some $xI + yP + z P^2$  where we note that $P^3 = I,$   so $(xI + yP + z P^2)^4 = x^4 I + other stuff$   and we want $I+P$ again

@user1551 I didn't obtain the spectral decomposition with a computer, I did it by hand but I used a computer to verify that such decomposition indeed yielded A. Unfortunately, I'm not familiar with the Lagrange interpolation polynomial, but your comment gave me an idea which I will test to see if it works. Thanks

if you want to do spectral decomposition, note that the diagonalizing matrix can be chosen to be a (normalized) Discrete Fourier Transform; the companion matrix  for $x^n-1$ always has this property
